# Increase Wordpress speed (large site around 1000k posts)

Tags: performance, wordpress

I have an wordpress site which has more than 1000k posts.Its very slow.I use use wp total cache,WP-dboptimizer plugin etc.But still it is slow.Can any one please give some tips to increase my site speed.My site is [amazingvideoz.com](http://amazingvideoz.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options. One of them is to use CDN..

I am giving you some articles that you should really follow. My site has become unbelievably faster after following them :-) (my blog - www.wrapcode.com, check the speed yourself)

1. Use Jetpack by Wordpress. Activate it, it really makes a lot of change in speed and performance. A type of CDN
2. Follow this article  : http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-install-and-setup-w3-total-cache-for-beginners/
3. use W3 Total Cache : I use this with Jetpack, it helps you to reduce bandwidth and speed up your blog : http://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/w3-total-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Try To Enable gzip with .htaccess file.

See this:

http://salscode.com/web-resources/gzip-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Using a CDN will definitely help if you have a lot of assets (images, js, css). If you are almost all html, a CDN does no good since its not going to cache the html. enabling gzip is always a good thing, though in most cases your hosting provider will have that covered. Use a web performance measurement tool like websitetest.com or webpagetest.org to get a feeling for whether the bottleneck is the front end or back end (server). If you see the first file (the main html) is taking a long time (over 1-2 seconds) then you really need to do more on the server. If you see 80-90% of the time on the rest of the files, you know you need to focus on the front-end and any changes to the server will do you minimal good.

So what to do on the back-end? Depends on how you are hosting. If you have an ultra-cheap plan , look at finding a better hosting option.

If you are like most of the websites out there, focusing on the front end is your best bet to see significant speedups. Take a look at the best practices on http://yslow.org/. follow most of those and you should see a very significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out various explanation and solutions of different factors affect on WordPress blog speed. it might help to work on specific that helps to increase speed.

Also you can cleaup wordpress database by wpclearfix plugin that will remove unwanted  revisions and  unwanted data from database and it will help to reduce database size as well.

for more details explanation you can check blog post on speedup WordPress blog -  http://www.blogtechie.com/speed-up-wordpress-blog-website/

also you can try lazy loading feature to load resources on demand basis

Answer (score 0):

For ultimate performance in Wordpress, here's what you need:

1. Use Nginx, do not ever use Apache - it doesn't scale well and consumes vast amounts of memory whereas Nginx is incredibly light weight. If your host only offers Apache, change hosts.
2. Use a CDN - cloudflare have a free CDN or MaxCDN is a premium service
3. Use W3 Total Cache and set up page caching and a CDN. Ignore the other settings as they can cause compatibility issues with other plugins.
4. Consider using HHVM - Hip Hop Virtual Machine, created by Facebook, basically makes PHP into a compiled language. It works in conjunction with Nginx. It doesn't work with Buddypress yet though so if you've got that, you need to wait.
5. Choose your hosting carefully - Digital Ocean offer SSD based VPS or WP Engine offer managed hosting and a lot of performance boosts (like HHVM, Varnish etc)
6. Consider setting up Varnish for more speed boosts
7. Consider setting up Memcached for even more speed boosts - either on the same server or a different dedicated caching server
8. Analyse the performance of your plugins - Query Monitor and P3 Plugin Profiler are pretty useful for this but ultimately the best option is New Relic which analyses performance over time in the background. Some plugins perform VERY badly when there are a lot of posts.

The above tips will give you sub-second speed on pretty much every possible size of Wordpress site you can imagine.

Here's a guide to setting up HHVM:

http://www.affiliatewebdesigners.com/2015/01/14/setting-hhvm-wordpress/

Here's a guide to configuring Digital Ocean with Nginx:

http://www.affiliatewebdesigners.com/2014/11/20/setting-digital-ocean-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

We have many options to apply on Wordpress for increase speed, you need to apply following points on your site.

1. Use CDN:Content Delivery Network (CDN)
2. Minify CSS/JS files
3. Remove render-blocking JavaScript
4. Apply Caching
5. CSS sprite
6. Install page speed module on the server
7. Improve server response time
8. Enable GZIP compression on the server
9. Apply AJAX to Speed Up
10. Add Expires headers to leverage browser caching

you can check full detail on [here](https://deorwine.com/blog/improve-your-websites-google-page-speed/)